# phpMyAdmin does not connect

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I use Apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin. Everything works except phpmyadmin, at first it's just a white sheet and after a while it gives the following error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught error: calling an undefined
> mb_detect_encoding() function in
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177
> Stack Trace: #0
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc
> (282): _encode('Extension %s...') ###1
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc
> (289): _gettext('Extension %s...') #2
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\core.lib.php (306):
> __('Extension %s...') #3
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\core.lib.php (972):
> PMA_warnMissingExtension('mbstring', true) #4
> C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\common.inc.php (102):
> PMA_checkExtensions() #5 C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\index.php
> (13): require_once('C:\Server\data \...')
> ##########################6 { the main} thrown in C:\Server\data\htdocs\pma\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on
> line 177"

I connected everything twice
What is problem?

I can't find anything on the Internet about this

Comment: Have you gone through our PHP ini file and ensured that the `mb` extensions are enabled? In the documentation it states: `"mbstring is a non-default extension. This means it is not enabled by default. You must explicitly enable the module with the configure option. "`

Comment: Your server hasn't installed `mbstring`.